# Setting Schema Name of Database in Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to set the Schema of a DbContext from the application that is referencing an assembly?

This is what I have now:

```
services.AddDbContext<ManagementStudioDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DSCASGlobals.DS_ConnectionString),
                    optionsBuilder =>
                        optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName)
                )
            );
```

ManagementStudioDbContext has a different schema and I was hoping to set it so that any calls back to ManagementStudio will always have a schema.

Comment: It seems you post multiple threads for your current projects with `ManagementStudio` and `DocumentStudio`. It would be helpful if there is any demo which could reproduce your issue directly. It's unclare your current implementation.

Comment: Yeah I'm focusing on different issues each time. I'm unable to show a demo. Would that mean recording a video?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify schema in `OnModelCreating` method

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().("User", schema: "acc");
```

Also you can use DataAnotation attribute

```
 [Table("User", Schema = "acc")]
 public class User{...}
```

Comment: Yeah I’ve done those things. The problem is when I reference managementstudio as a dll, I get an error when I login saying that it’s looking for identityuserclaims which is a table without a schema

Comment: @JianYA “reference managementstudio as a dll” - what does it mean?

Comment: It means I am referencing a dll called ManagementStudio.